# Dropdown Menus In Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, drupal-6, navigation

I have my Drupal site here so far: selkirk.treethink.net
Each Primary Link at the top has a bunch of other primary links under it (sub links)
I need to display these sub links when you hover over the parent primary link in a dropdown menu.

Everything is in the primary links but there are parents (what you see at the top of the demo) and sub links (what should be in the dropdown). I'm not sure if I set up these menus wrong though...Drupal is a little awkward for me.

I did download this module but I am not sure how to get it going to automatically dropdown a primary link's submenu items when rolled over: http://drupal.org/project/jquery_dropdown

Thanks,
Wade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown module you installed is to transform a "`<select>`" dropdown element into a jQuery dropdown and is not exactly for menu/navigation purpose that you want.

You might want to check the [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/node/43047) module.